# Why does the bash script in my docker build file return corrupt json?

Tags: json, bash, docker, nuget

**Why is docker build corrupting the JSON in $VSS_NUGET_EXTERNAL_FEED_ENDPOINTS?**

I am using [this article](https://somakdas.medium.com/private-nuget-package-restore-in-docker-build-azure-devops-431fdfeae557) (spefically example 2 which uses *Buildkit* and *docker build secrets*) to help populate my Dockerfile. The process will:

- pass a PAT during `docker build`,
- mount the PAT as a secret,
- export an escaped JSON string using the secret (via `cat /pat`) to ENV, and

  - ^^^ the above JSON is corrupt ^^^
- use the env variable to call a NuGet private feed before
- making a `dotnet restore` request.

The bash command in question is:

```
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=pat,dst=/pat export VSS_NUGET_EXTERNAL_FEED_ENDPOINTS="{\"endpointCredentials\": [{\"endpoint\":\"https://<my private feed URL>/nuget/v3/index.json\", \"username\":\"docker\", \"password\":\"`cat /pat`\"}]}" && \
  echo $VSS_NUGET_EXTERNAL_FEED_ENDPOINTS
```

Output of the echo command (notice the trailing end of the PAT is appended AFTER the JSON closing braces):

```
{"endpointCredentials": [{"endpoint":"https://<my private feed URL>/nuget/v3/index.json", "username":"docker", "password":"qwak...jiq5"}]}vtzkzv4a
```

When I run the command in bash (in Windows Subsystem for Linux) it works just fine:

```
~ echo "my-pat-token" >> /pat
~ export MY_ENV_VAR="{\"endpointCredentials\": [{\"endpoint\":\"https://<URL of private feed>/nuget/v3/index.json\", \"username\":\"build\", \"password\":\"`cat /pat`\"}]}"
~ echo $MY_ENV_VAR
{"endpointCredentials": [{"endpoint":"https://<URL of private feed>/nuget/v3/index.json", "username":"build", "password":"my-pat-token"}]}
```

Dockerfile:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1.2

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1 AS build
WORKDIR /src

# Install NuGet credential provider
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y locales \
   && sed -i -e 's/# en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8/' /etc/locale.gen \
   && dpkg-reconfigure --frontend=noninteractive locales && update-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8 \
   # Download the artifact credential provider
   && wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Microsoft/artifacts-credprovider/master/helpers/installcredprovider.sh | bash

COPY NuGet.Config .

COPY ["src/Discovery.Api/Discovery.Api.csproj", "src/Discovery.Api/"]
COPY ["src/Discovery.Service/Discovery.Service.csproj", "src/Discovery.Service/"]
COPY ["src/Discovery.Data/Discovery.Data.csproj", "src/Discovery.Data/"]

# Use the secret to set the credential provider variable and run restore.
ENV NUGET_CREDENTIALPROVIDER_SESSIONTOKENCACHE_ENABLED true
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=pat,dst=/pat export VSS_NUGET_EXTERNAL_FEED_ENDPOINTS="{\"endpointCredentials\": [{\"endpoint\":\"https://<my private feed URL>/nuget/v3/index.json\", \"username\":\"docker\", \"password\":\"`cat /pat`\"}]}" && \
  echo $VSS_NUGET_EXTERNAL_FEED_ENDPOINTS

RUN dotnet restore "src/Discovery.Api/Discovery.Api.csproj" --configfile NuGet.Config

COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Discovery.Api"
RUN dotnet build "src/Discovery.Api/Discovery.Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "src/Discovery.Api/Discovery.Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "src/Discovery.Api/Discovery.Api.dll"]
```

docker build command:

```
docker build --no-cache --progress=plain --secret id=pat,src=./pat -t discovery-api:dev -f src\Discovery.Api\Dockerfile .
```

docker --version

```
Docker version 20.10.8, build 3967b7d
```

I am running docker on linux containers.

Comment: does the pat file contain carriage returns or newlines?

Comment: If `pat` contains (Microsoft) CRLF line ends, one could try `sed 's/\r$//' /pat` instead of `cat`, or perhaps `tr -d '\r' < /pat`.

Comment: @glen jackman "does the pat file contain carriage returns or newlines?" - YES! I removed the newline at the end of the file and this has solved it, thank you!

Comment: @dan - yes it did contain line ends; in this instance I was able to manually delete the line end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the advice from @glenn jackman and @dan in the comments, I found the `/pat` file had a newline at the end of the file. Deleting the newline solved the json problem.